# Crud Destroy isnt Destroying

Tags: php, laravel

Im doing my first CRUD(Vue-Laravel) and im getting an error in the backend.

My Laravel.Log:

```
[2020-11-29 00:13:31] local.ERROR: Call to a member function delete() on null {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function delete() on null at C:\\Users\\DEUS GUILHERME\\Documents\\GitHub\\dadus-financeiro-backend\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\DespesaController.php:49)
[stacktrace]
```

My backend:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
  $despesa = Despesa::find($id);

  $despesa->delete();

  return response()->json('Delete Sucessful');
}
```

My frontend:

```
async deleteDespesa(id) {
  const response = await axios.delete("api/despesas/{despesa}").then((response) => {
          this.despesas.splice(this.despesas.indexOf(id), 1);
  this.getDespesa();
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Despesa::findOrFail($id)` to make sure that the object is correctly fetched?

Comment: I mean, clearly the `find()` function is returning `null` but you're not checking for that. Make sure your route is defined with `{id}` somewhere in the path, otherwise the `$id` variable means nothing.

Comment: I did Despesa::findOrFail($id), now im getting this error: Error: Request failed with status code 404

Comment: I will edit with my frontend delete

Comment: Try that `const response = await axios.delete("api/despesas/"+id).then((response) => {});`

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!!! THANK YOU BOTH SO MUCH!!!!!!!!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to mark that answer as successful! ;)

Comment: I'm late to the edit, with that front end, everything makes sense. Glad that someone was there to tell you the solution before me! Allow me to further explain why it works: `{id}` should only be written in the route declaration (PHP). In all other cases, like an AJAX request through axios, the actual number must be placed instead, that's why concatenating the actual id number in JS works! I'll upvote the answer.

Comment: Wow, i didnt know that!  Thanks for the explaining!

Comment: You're welcome. Think of it like this: axios will do something like accessing the path through a web browser, so if you type `/api/despesa/104` for the "Despesa" of ID 104, then the 104 must be there. But in PHP, you have something like `Route::post('/api/despesas/{id}')` and that `{id}` translates into `$id` in the controller. If you had declared `Route::post('/api/despesas/{despesa}')` (which I do), you could do something like this in your controller: `destroy(Despesa $despesa)` and that executes `findOrFail()` for you (it's automated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at your front-end, you'll see that you don't specify an ID you want to delete.

You can fix that by replacing

`await axios.delete("api/despesas/{despesa}").then((response) => {});`

with

`const response = await axios.delete("api/despesas/"+id).then((response) => {});`